# Assigning new Python object to a variable vs passing new object directly in a recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, pass-by-reference

The code below is a solution to an LC question ("Maximum Difference Between Node and Ancestor").

I create a copy of the set to split values between left and right subtrees (so non-ancestors aren't compared). When I assign that copy to `vals2` and pass `vals2` to the helper function, the solution works as expected. When I pass `vals.copy()` directly to that function, the solution breaks.

I think I must be misunderstanding scope or something. In my mind the code should execute identically whether the set is assigned to a variable or not. What is happening here?

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    def maxAncestorDiff(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        ans = [float('-inf')]

        def helper(node, vals):
            if vals:
                diff = max(abs(max(vals) - node.val), abs(min(vals) - node.val))
                ans[0] = max(ans[0], diff)
            vals.add(node.val)
            vals2 = vals.copy() # Must assign to vals2 for it to work
            if node.left:
                # Fails if I pass copy directly (exceeds memory limit)
                helper(node.left, vals.copy())
            if node.right:
                helper(node.right, vals)

        helper(root, set())
        return ans[0]
```

Comment: The difference is in whether you make the copy before or after calling `helper(node.left, vals)`, which adds additional values to `vals`

Comment: Good call, you're right. But passing `vals.copy()` to the first function call instead of the second also causes this to fail, but for a different reason (memory limit exceeded). This still violates my understanding of how the code should execute -- assigning it to a variable first is somehow different, I don't understand why.

Comment: If the aim is for `helper` to have no side effects on the set that is passed to it, the safest way is to make the copy (`vals=vals.copy()`) at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Assigning to a variable should make no difference beyond changing the time at which a copy is made. The problem is changes to vals in one function call affecting lots of others. Adding some `print(node, vals)` or debugging should help see what is happening here.

Comment: Your current code seems to work - what is the input that is causing it to exceed memory limit?

Comment: Assigning a copy to a variable and also passing a copy to the function makes two copies of the set, which explains why memory limit may be exceeded with long input. Either assigning it to a variable and passing that variable, or passing the copy as a parameter without creating another variable, will reduce the memory use.

Comment: You got it Stuart. At first it failed because of the order helper was called in, then it failed because my code was still making a new set for the unused `vals2` variable and exceeded memory limit. I feel silly now, was confused by the side effects in recursive function, but this all makes sense now. :) Thanks.